# Can I run windows containers using docker-toolbox on windows 7?

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox

I want to run a container with microsoft/windowsservercore.

This can be done if docker server's OS is windows. I couldn't find an answer for whether it is possible using docker-toolbox in windows 7.

Answer (score 27):

No, Docker Toolbox installs a VirtualBox VM in which a minimal Linux is installed to run Docker Linux containers.

Running Native Windows containers [requires Windows 10 professional, or Windows Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/index).

Docker for Windows allows you to [toggle between "Linux" and "Windows" containers](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#/switch-between-windows-and-linux-containers), but also requires Windows 10 Professional or Enterprise

Comment: What about running windows containers on server 2016 with Docker? I installed ToolBox since Docker for Windows is not supported, but the toolbox does not support Windows Containers.

Comment: Windows Server 2016 can run Windows Native Containers; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/quick-start-windows-server

Comment: Thank you for the response, I was able to get that to work, issue now on server is trying to use compose with VS, I actually asked a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45173859/using-docker-in-hyper-v-with-windows-server-2016

Comment: There's a conflicting issue whereby even if you're running Win10 you can't install docker for Windows if you need to also run Virtualbox, as it clashes with HyperV.

Comment: Possibly in future, VirtualBox will no longer be able to run on Windows (even without Docker installed), because Hyper-V will be used for other parts of Windows as well (see https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2850#issuecomment-358377520)