# Docker Toolbox image operating system "windows" cannot be used on this platform

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox

I have installed docker toolbox on my windows 10 home pc. 
I ma facing two problems.

1.When I click on docker quickstart terminal, it gives unix/linux prompt.
2.When I try to run this command docker build (on windows command prompt), I get this error :image operating system "windows" cannot be used on this platform.

```
docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.584MB
Step 1/17 : FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0-nanoserver-1709 AS base
2.0-nanoserver-1709: Pulling from microsoft/aspnetcore
407ada6e90de: Pulling fs layer
10288d944410: Pulling fs layer
4880fefbf99e: Pulling fs layer
df193da25173: Waiting
60ab1f0af432: Waiting
f4d477fb2108: Waiting
878954290d5e: Waiting
ae61d8e352f7: Waiting
88faab7b6014: Waiting
e7331f21ccb7: Waiting
image operating system "windows" cannot be used on this platform
```

How do I correct my configuration so that it accepts my windows 10 os.

How can I configure docker toolbox so that I can dockerize my dot net applications.

My question is, if docker toolbox installs a linux vm on my system, how is it going to help me with commands like " docker build ." , it gives this error :image operating system "windows" cannot be used on this platform. So, essentially, I cannot do anything.

Is that correct? or is there a way by which I can invoke docker on windows 10 home?

Thanks is advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I run windows containers using docker-toolbox on windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42482154/can-i-run-windows-containers-using-docker-toolbox-on-windows-7)

Comment: My question is, if docker toolbox installs a linux vm on my system, hiw is it going to help me with commands like " docker build ." , it gives this error :image operating system "windows" cannot be used on this platform. So, essentially, I cannot do anything.

Is that correct? or is there a way by which I can invoke docker on windows 10 home?

Answer (score 1):

Change to `FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0-nanoserver-1709` to `microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime`

Explanation:

`microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0-nanoserver-1709 is a windows native container image.` It can only be run on windows 10 or windows server.To run on Linux container, pull the similar image for Linux as described [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnetcore/)

Comment: This just explains how to switch to a linux based image. But Windows 10 should be able to run the Windows based image, how can we do that?

Answer (score 1):

To be able to run Windows containers, you first need to install Hyper-V: open PowerShell as an administrator and enter `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName $("Microsoft-Hyper-V", "Containers") -All`. Restart your computer, launch Docker Desktop and then right click on Docker Desktop at the bottom right the windows task bar, and click "Switch to windows container"

[image]

You should now be able to run any docker image based on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the last answer, I changed my base to: microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
and the build to microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build in the Dockerfile and now it works.