# Run docker container on host machine on windows 7

Tags: docker

I have a windows 7 machine. I wish to use docker so that I can package my windows binaries and dependencies and give them to my client without giving them explicit instructions.

My client is also on windows 7. 
My client is not interested in running any VM  on his windows 7 machine.

Can docker help me here?
What I found on internet is that one can use windows server 2016 and above to achieve this functionality but not windows 7 ...

any help?

Comment: You can run windows containers on *Docker for Windows* but not on *Docker-toolbox* which is for Win 7. Check this: [Can I run windows containers using docker-toolbox on windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42482154/can-i-run-windows-containers-using-docker-toolbox-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can install docker on Windows 7.
The install pre-requisite for docker is Windows 10 (or [natively on Windows server 2016](https://blog.docker.com/2016/09/dockerforws2016/))
Please see [this link](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/) which is the docker install for windows.

Here is the content from the page for posterity:

> System Requirements:
>
> - Windows 10 64bit: Pro, Enterprise or Education (1607 Anniversary Update, Build 14393 or later).
> - Virtualization is enabled in BIOS. Typically, virtualization is enabled by default. This is different from having Hyper-V enabled. For more detail see Virtualization must be enabled in Troubleshooting.
> - CPU SLAT-capable feature.
> - At least 4GB of RAM.

If you are locked into Windows binaries, then I don't know of a good solution for you unless you upgrade to he latest Windows OS, but if you can run your code on Linux then you can either use a free Linux OS and host your container there, or if you really must, you can spin up a VM on your Win 7 machine to host linux and run your container.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there are two versions of Docker for the Windows platform: [Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox) and [Docker For Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/).

Only the former runs on Windows 7. It's a legacy solution though and doesn't let you package or run Windows containers - only Linux ones. For Windows-type containers you need the latter one, but then an upgrade of both yours and your client's machine is needed (as [Jay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/685341/jay) mentioned in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52963516/4494577)):

> **System Requirements**:
>
> - Windows 10 64bit: Pro, Enterprise or Education (1607 Anniversary Update, Build 14393 or later).
> - Virtualization is enabled in BIOS. Typically, virtualization is enabled by default. This is different from having Hyper-V enabled. For more detail see [Virtualization must be enabled](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#virtualization-must-be-enabled) in Troubleshooting.
> - CPU SLAT-capable feature.
> - At least 4GB of RAM.
>
> -- https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#what-to-know-before-you-install

Currently there's no other way to run Windows containers in Docker.